# How to prevent keydown event listener from listening while inputting to a text field?

Tags: javascript

This is my additional code for reddit. It helps me browse it much quicker. The idea is based on 4chan's keyboard shortcuts. 'N' key for the next page and 'B' for the previous.

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
function checkKeyPressed(e){
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 66:
            window.location = document.querySelector('a[rel="nofollow prev"]').href;
            break;
        case 78:
            window.location = document.querySelector('a[rel="nofollow next"]').href;
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

My problem is, the event also occurs when I type into a text field with the words that has 'n' or 'b' in it. How do I prevent it from happening when I focus to a text field?

Comment: You can also put a class on elements to ignore and check *e.target.className*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As noted out by [zerkms](https://stackoverflow.com/users/251311/zerkms): i am not sure if you also want to detect text area's you should enhance the code further if you need support for such case...

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
function checkKeyPressed(e){
    var elem = e.target;
    var type = elem.getAttribute("type");
    if(type!='text'){
    switch(e.keyCode){
        case 66:
            //window.location = document.querySelector('a[rel="nofollow prev"]').href;
            alert("case 66");
            break;
        case 78:
            //window.location = document.querySelector('a[rel="nofollow next"]').href;
            alert("case 78");
            break;
        default:
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thank you. Shortened it further by not putting var and typing `type=e.target.getAttribute("type")` instead.